# bloodhound resetting local data

Tags: javascript, jquery, bloodhound

Im using bloodhound and trying to reset the `local` option. on my webpage I have a situation whereby If the user chooses one of two options the suggestion data will change. But I cant get the suggestions to appear when I set the local data. Below is how I create the bloodhound setting it up to use an array called 'spray':

```
var dataSetBloodhound = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  local: spray
});
```

So if the user chooses spray jQuery catches it and tries to set the spray array to the local

```
 //If spray is picked  
        if( checked == "Spray") {
            // Clear the object
            dataSetBloodhound.clear();
            // Set the local 'data' to spray
            dataSetBloodhound.local = spray;
            // Reinit the object
            dataSetBloodhound.initialize()
            // Prints out the local data.(This prints out the data of spray)
            console.log(dataSetBloodhound.local);
            //etc }
```

If the user chooses fertilizer the function is the same as above except a `fertilizer` array is passed.
If I use on list i can get them to work but I cant seem to swap the local data of bloodhound. Yet after I `initialize()` I can `console.log(dataSetBloodhound.local)` and I can view the elements in the console but if I try and get a suggestion from the dropdown it doesnt work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to reinitialize, you can set

```
if( checked == "Spray") {
        // Clear the object
        dataSetBloodhound.clear();
        // Set the local 'data' to spray
        dataSetBloodhound.local = spray;
        // Reinit the object
        dataSetBloodhound.initialize(true);
        // Prints out the local data.(This prints out the data of spray)
        console.log(dataSetBloodhound.local);
```

Please check the documentation https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md